# Protools 10 trial

Tags: post-production

I had pt 8 on an old pc and I have moved to a trail version of pt10 on a new pc.
I want to move permanently to pt10. Should I uninstall the trial version first or just update to PT10 from the trial version?
I also didn’t download the plugins on the trial version, how do I go back and get those?

Answer (score 2):

Also I think it'd be great if you wait for a while. PT11 is rumoured to be released in April. I'd wait and check out what's different between 10 and 11.

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that you only need a full license on your iLok, but check out this thread or contact avid support:

http://duc.avid.com/showthread.php?t=313982